# Confusion about Jump size of a floor function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Suppose one defines the following floor function $$ \lfloor x \rfloor , 0\leq x \leq N~~~~\text{for some finite integer}~~ N$$ 
First question: Can we say that the jump size is $+1$?

What if one has the following:
$$ \lfloor M \rfloor$$ I am not sure how to define this, but I want a floor function which starts at a number $M$ and decreases by $1$ to $0$.

In this case is the jump size $+1$ or $-1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can say that the "jump size" is $+1$. We can define jump size of $f(x)$ at $x=a$ by

$$j_f(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)-\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$$

In the case of the floor function, this becomes $N-(N-1)=1$ for integral $N$. Note that a function may have different jump sizes at different places, so we must make the jump size a function as well, not a constant, though we could talk about the supremum jump size over all real numbers. This "jump size" at a point is used in various proofs, for example that the discontinuities in a monotonic function are at most countably infinite.

One function that "starts at a number $M$ and decreases by $1$ to $0$" is

$$g(x)=\lfloor M-x \rfloor$$

Then $g(0)=M$, $g(M)=0$ for integral $M$. And using the "jump size" definition I gave, $j_g(a)$ is $-1$ if $a\in\Bbb Z$, $0$ otherwise. So the jump size is $-1$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. $M-\lfloor x\rfloor$ the same as $g(x)$?

Comment: @Joel: Yes, if $M$ is an integer, otherwise no.